# How can I get a free SP 2013 account for trial

Tags: 2013, office-365

I want to hold a demo for one of our clients regarding the SP 2013, but when I try to create an Office 365 trail account from https://portal.microsoftonline.com/Signup/MainSignUp.aspx

I am getting the following error:

> This doesn't look like a valid user ID. Make sure you typed the user ID assigned to you by your organization. It usually looks like someone@example.com or someone@example.onmicrosoft.com.

Answer (score 3):

Most Likely you are using wrong credentials to login and best way to get it resolved is to contact Microsoft.

However the link you provided is saying that the demo offer by Microsoft is no longer available.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the sharepoint 2013 foundation?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a 14 day trial at www.cloudshare.com, its sharepoint 2013 RTM on premises but hosted on the cloud, its not sharepoint line.

The one you are trying to subscribe its sharepoint online and has many different(less) features than on premises.

Also SharePoint Online 2013 Preview would expire this week and all accounts were going to be deleted.  The preview ended and YOU HAVE to pay.

Don't be cheap:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/collaboration-tools-compare-sharepoint-plans-FX103789400.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**SharePoint Online** (Office 365)

You can "[Sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/apps/fp179924%28v=office.15%29)" which will cost you $99.00 per year for an Office 365 developer subscription.

You might get one for free if you are a MSDN subscriber or a (Plan E1 or E3) Office 365 subscriber

You could also become a Microsoft Cloud Essentials Partner which will get you 25 seats of Microsoft Office 365.

**SharePoint 2013**

As Luis said, **please note that there are important functional differences between SharePoint Online (part of Office 365) and a SharePoint 2013 on-premises installation**. So in order to give a full demo, you could set up your own server using the free "SharePoint Foundation 2013" version or "SharePoint Server 2013 - 180-day trial (with enterprise features)".

There is a ready to use template on Azure that you could use: [Get Started with SharePoint Server 2013 Quickly on Windows Azure](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2013/04/16/get-started-with-sharepoint-server-2013-fast-on-windows-azure.aspx)

And then there also are the Contoso images...